# Adjust ng-repeat to match object structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object which looks like this:

```
 $scope.hobbies = {
    list: [
      {
        "PersonId": 23,
        "PersonName": "John Smith",
        "Hobbies": [
          {
            "HobbyTitle": "Paragliding",
            "HobbyId": 23
          },
          {
            "HobbyTitle": "Sharking",
            "HobbyId": 99
          }
        ]
      }             
    ]
   };
```

I'm trying to develop a view which allows users to make a selection of each person's hobby.

I have a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xobJYYUA8u995cuREi7e?p=preview)

My problem is that all selected hobbies are displayed under every person. This is because I'm just pushing all selected hobbies to a selectedHobbies Array.

```
  $scope.addHobbyItem = function (item) {
    var index = $scope.selectedHobbies.list.indexOf(item);
    if (index === -1) {
      $scope.selectedHobbies.list.push(item);
    }
  };
```

This of course doesn't work, as once a hobby is selected, it is shown under every person. How could I adjust the code to work with the way I'm ng-repeating over the selectedHobbies?

The HTML is below. I'm also using a directive to listen to click on the hobby container and trigger addHobbyItem()

```
<div data-ng-repeat="personHobby in hobbies.list">
  <div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; margin: 10px 0 10px">
      <strong>{{ personHobby.PersonName }}</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div data-ng-repeat="hobby in personHobby.Hobbies" data-ng-if="!hobby.selected">
          <div data-hobby-item="" data-selected-list="false" data-ng-class="{ selected : hobby.selected }"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div data-ng-repeat="hobby in selectedHobbies.list">
          <div data-hobby-item="" data-selected-list="true"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put all your _relevant_ code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your selectedHobbies should be a map in which the key is the person id and the value is a list of his selected hobbies. [checkout this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2j451njy4Ij6IEZI2yr2?p=preview)

```
  $scope.selectedHobbies = {
    map: {}
  };

  // Add a hobby to our selected items
  $scope.addHobbyItem = function(pid, item) {
    if(!$scope.selectedHobbies.map[pid]) {
      $scope.selectedHobbies.map[pid] = [];
    }
    var index = $scope.selectedHobbies.map[pid].indexOf(item);
    if (index === -1) {
      $scope.selectedHobbies.map[pid].push(item);
    }
  };
```

in the directive call addHobbyItem with the person id

```
scope.addHobbyItem(scope.personHobby.PersonId, scope.hobby);
```

and lastly in you html iterate on each person's selected hobbies

```
    <div data-ng-repeat="hobby in selectedHobbies.map[personHobby.PersonId]">
      <div data-hobby-item="" class="add-remove-container--offence" data-selected-list="true"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. The map idea is great, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/7BtzfCQNTCb9yYkv1uPN?p=preview

I used the $parent.$index to create an array of arrays containing hobbies for each person.

```
 $scope.addHobbyItem = function (item, index) {

     var ine = $scope.selectedHobbies[index].indexOf(item);
     if (ine === -1) {
        $scope.selectedHobbies[index].push(item);
     }
 };

 function hobbyClickEvent() {
    if (!$(element).hasClass('selected')) {

      scope.addHobbyItem(scope.hobby, scope.$parent.$index);
    } else {
      scope.removeHobbyItem(scope.hobby);
    }
  }
```

and in the HTML:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="hobby in selectedHobbies[$index]">
    <div data-hobby-item="" class="add-remove-container--offence" data-selected-list="true"></div>
</div>
```